# Filling a Spinner from DataBase android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, ormlite

I'm working on a project in which i have to get some informations from the server save them in database using ormlite and after i want to display those informations on a spinner,

So to get the informations from the database to the spinner i called this method:

```
  public Dao<ServiceProviderCompanies, Integer> getTowServiceProviderCompaniesDao() {
        if (null == towServiceProviderCompaniesDao) {
            try {
                towServiceProviderCompaniesDao = getDao(ServiceProviderCompanies.class);
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return towServiceProviderCompaniesDao;
    }
```

i called it in my activity in like this:

```
String[] ServicePCompanies;

 try {List<ServiceProviderCompanies> mSerProCom=towManager.getTowServiceProviderCompaniesDao().queryForAll();
            ServicePCompanies=new String[mSerProCom.size()];
            for(int i=1;i<mSerProCom.size();i++){
                ServicePCompanies[i]=mSerProCom.get(i)._serviceRequesterServiceProviderCompany;
            }
            //CompaniesForSpinner=towManager.getTowServiceProviderCompaniesDao().queryForAll().toString();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i filled my spinner using these lines of code

```
Spinner entrAssistanceList=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpNomEntrAssis);
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ServicePCompanies);
        spinnerArrayAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        entrAssistanceList.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

when i do so i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:454)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1427)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:714)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:604)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1427)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:714)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:604)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1228)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:326)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1427)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:714)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:604)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:326)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1427)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:714)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:604)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4952)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:326)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2209)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15811)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2232)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1310)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1505)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4962)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5449)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

knowing that i tryed to fill the Spinner with an Array that i created manually:

```
ServicePCompaniesArray=new String[]{"Entreprise1","Entreprise2","Entreprise3"};
```

and i don't get the error so i think that the problem is when i get the informations from the database, knwoing that i debugged it and the String Array that i'm giving to the adapter is filled with the information that i get from the database, so really i don't know where the NullPointerException comes from

Thank you guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to put your data in this array

```
String[] ServicePCompanies;
```

just use the list you get from the database

```
List<ServiceProviderCompanies> mSerProCom=towManager.getTowServiceProviderCompaniesDao().queryForAll();
```

don't forget to override toString() method in your object (ServiceProviderCompanies)

Answer (score 0):

At first print your array to Log to make sure sure about your array then do that. If the array contains null then it will give you NullPointerException.So first check the array.Better you can put a if statement to check if the array is empty or not?

Thanks..

EDIT

please replace:

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ServicePCompanies);
```

with this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ServicePCompanies);
```

hope it will work..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i've checked if the array contains any null but the array doesn't contain, the crash happens when i want to display the spinner not when i fill it, the spinner is also filled with the information i want to display, but when i want to display it, it crash, thank you

Comment: i tryed this one also, the problem is not in filling the ArrayAdapter the  problem is in displaying the Spinner that contains that ArrayAdapter

Comment: Print the whole array in Log..then post it